# Bank account data structure

Tags: python, interview-questions, finance

I need to model simple account data structure. The user should be able:

- to add a transaction
- get information about transaction
- take all transaction of some type
- sum a transaction and all its children

---

```
class AccountModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = {}
        self.amounts = {}
        self.parent_to_chilren = {}
        self.children_to_parent = {}
        self.of_type = {}

    def add(self, id, amount, type, parentId=None):
        assert(
            not(id in self.amounts),
            'there is already a transaction with such id'
        )
        self.amounts[id] = amount
        self.of_type[id] = type

        lstOfType = self.types.get(type, [])
        lstOfType.append(id)
        self.types[type] = lstOfType

        if parentId:
            self.children_to_parent[id] = parentId
            lstOfChilren = self.parent_to_chilren.get(parentId, [])
            lstOfChilren.append(id)
            self.parent_to_chilren[parentId] = lstOfChilren

    def get(self, id):
        return (
            self.amounts[id], self.of_type[id],
            self.children_to_parent.get(id, None)
        )

    def get_list_by_type(self, type):
        return self.types[type]

    def sum(self, id):
        lst = self.parent_to_chilren.get(id, [])
        res = self.amounts[id]
        for i in lst:
            res += self.sum(i)
        return res
```

And the tests:

```
import unittest

from challenge import AccountModel
class AccountModelTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.model = AccountModel()

    def test_can_add_a_transaction_and_get_information(self):
        self.model.add(1, 10, 'car')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.get(1),
            (10, 'car', None),
        )

    def test_can_add_a_transaction_and_get_information_with_parent_id(self):
        self.model.add(1, 10, 'car')
        self.model.add(2, 10, 'car', 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.get(2),
            (10, 'car', 1),
        )

    def test_can_add_few_transactions_of_a_different_type_and_them(self):
        self.model.add(1, 10, 'car')
        self.model.add(2, 15, 'shopping')
        self.model.add(3, 18, 'car')
        self.assertItemsEqual(
            self.model.get_list_by_type('car'),
            [1, 3]
        )

    def test_can_add_few_transactions_of_a_different_type_and_calc_sum(self):
        self.model.add(1, 10, 'car')
        self.model.add(2, 15, 'shopping', 1)
        self.model.add(3, 18, 'car')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.sum(1),
            25
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.sum(2),
            15
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.sum(3),
            18
        )

    def test_can_add_few_transactions_parent_of_parent_of_parent(self):
        self.model.add(1, 10, 'car')
        self.model.add(2, 15, 'shopping', 1)
        self.model.add(3, 18, 'car', 2)
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.sum(1),
            43
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model.sum(2),
            33
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The questions:

- Is there a more effective (in terms of used memory) implementation?
- Is there a way to change a data structure and provide more effective (in terms of complexity) `sum` function implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem statement is a bit unclear,I'm uncertain what they mean by the children of a transition. In addition I would ask the interviewer what types (categories) of transaction it should support. Let's assume the basic ones, withdrawal, deposit and transfers.

I wouldn't store this information directly into the `AccountModel`, instead I would create a `Transaction` class which holds information regarding the transaction which is general and present for each type of transaction, namely: an `id`, `amount`, `timestamp`.

Then you can create subclasses `Withdrawal`, `Deposit` and `Transfer`, these can then be stored in a list of account which represents the history of the account's actions. An action is then performed by creating the action: `account.perform(Withdrawal(10))`, where `account`is the an object of the `AccountModel`class. In the `perform()`method I would check the type of transaction and update the account balance accordingly (which you store in the account directly). This way you don't need to use the `sum()`to run over the list of transactions each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thoughts:

- **Use snake_case for all variable names.** This is the naming convention endorsed by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

  (If you can’t remember what the style is for an interview, at least be consistent – I see both snake_case and camelCase in this short script.
- **Don’t use asserts as a substitute for exceptions.** Asserts are for ensuring a program hasn’t reached an impossible state, whereas it is quite possible that a user could try to create two transactions with the same ID. You should raise an Exception instead.

  Supplementary question:
- **Should the user be managing their own ids?** If you want to enforce uniqueness, perhaps the AccountModel class should be managing ID numbers? Perhaps that’s a detail that a user shouldn’t worry about? How does a user know what’s a valid ID? etc.

  For the caller’s internal bookkeeping, you could create an ID for them, and return it from the add() method.
- **Your data model is quite confusing.** I made a quick diagram to follow where inputs to the `add()` method go. Here it is:

  [image]

  There’s lots of duplicate information (which is quite memory inefficient), and it’s not immediately obvious which attributes I should be inspecting if I want information about a transaction.

  I’d suggest creating a flat dict of transactions, in which the keys are IDs (auto-generated by the class), and the values are [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) representing a single transaction. This is much more memory efficient.

  You then implement things like the `transactions_of_type` attribute by doing a list comprehension over this list.
- **Use better variable names.** Things like `i`, `lst` and `res` in the `sum()` method aren’t very meaningful.

Comment: What do you propose instead of `i`, `lst` and `res`?:)